# angular 2 bootstrap 4 cancel esc key event

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I need help with catching ESC key event and cancel it. I've opened Bootstrap 4 modal and configured it so ESC key can close it.
Now this code is not working and I'm trying to figure out what to do ..  so any idea would be appreciated ...

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
 if (event.keyCode == 27) {
    // ...
    //some logic to resolve if esc key should be canceled ...
    // ...
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to achieve anything specific to `modal`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to relate to Bootstrap 4 at all

Comment: yes it does ... I heve an open modal window and modal window in boostrap binds to ESC key if configured. Since I need ESC key to close the modal I enabled it.. But I have a case where ESC key event must be catched and event propagation must be stoppped. And I'm asking how to do it .. As tags suggest I'm using Angular2 and Boostrap 4 for angular 2
Sorry. I've updated main post to describe it ...

Comment: @Armando is it out of the question to use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io)? Their modals support this.

Comment: no .. I'm using it ! They support ESC key .. and it's working fine .. but I cant catch the event and stop it's propagation ..